# DRY Spring AnnotationConfig testing

Tags: spring, testing, spring-test

So, I'm working on some Spring tests which require dependency injection using annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class BeanTest {

  @Autowired
  private SomeService someService;

  @Configuration
  static class ContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SomeService someService() {
        return new SomeService();
    }
  }
}
```

I'd really like to not have to repeat this code in every test but my attempts to create a base class which contains the configuration:

```
@Configuration
class MyContextConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public SomeService someService() {
       return new SomeService();
   }
}
```

And deriving from it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class BeanTest {

  @Autowired
  private SomeService someService;

  @Configuration
  static class ContextConfiguration extends MyContextConfiguration {}
}
```

Don't seem to work.  Can anybody suggest a way to DRY this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this instead.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BeanTest {

  @Autowired
  private SomeService someService;

  @Configuration
  @Import(MyContextConfiguration.class)
  static class ContextConfiguration {
  ....
  }
}
```

Also, you don't need to mention `AnnotationConfigContextLoader`, Spring by convention will automatically pick up the static inner class annotated with `@Configuration` and use the appropriate ContextLoader

Comment: It looks like that @Import annotation needs to replace the inner class and annotations.  If you can remove that, I can accept this...

Comment: Not `MyContextConfiguration`, but `ContextConfiguration` in your sample above, and since that is importing `MyContextConfiguration`, all the beans from that should be visible in the test ..essentially any static class annotated with @Configuraiton..here is a small blog article with more information on the defaults - http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/08/contextconfiguration-defaults.html

Answer (score 1):

You can declare configuration classes in the the contextconfiguration-annotation. From the documentation.

ContextConfiguration
Defines class-level metadata that is used to determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for integration tests. Specifically, @ContextConfiguration declares the application context resource locations or the annotated classes that will be used to load the context.
Resource locations are typically XML configuration files located in the classpath; whereas, annotated classes are typically @Configuration classes. However, resource locations can also refer to files in the file system, and annotated classes can be component classes, etc.

example from the documentation.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class ConfigClassApplicationContextTests {
    // class body...
}
```